# MySQL: How can I convert a string like "1 h 15 min" into 75?

Tags: mysql

Is it posssible to convert a string like `"1 h 15 min"` into `75` with a **SQL only** solution?

**Edit:**

The string may also be in the format `"1 h"` or `"15 min"` in some cases, but it never contains days and seconds.

Comment: What is the reason of using only SQL?

Comment: Is the format always _exactly_ like that, or can it be just '1 h' or '15 min' or '2 days 1 h 15 min 2 sec'?

Comment: Are you opposed to User Defined Functions? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: @Jari I'm wondering if it's possible to do it with SQL only. I know many other ways of doing it.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I've edited my question based on your comment.

Comment: Does CONVERT(datetime, '1 h', 120) work? I had no time to test it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short hack:

```
SET @ugly_time = '1h 2min';
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(
    COALESCE(
        STR_TO_DATE(@ugly_time, '%Hh %imin'),
        STR_TO_DATE(@ugly_time, '%imin')
    )
) AS seconds;
```

(works only for times < 24h)

Comment: ah, still have to drink my coffee, `coalesce()`, ... nice +1

Comment: @HeinA.Grønnestad Ahem, obviously, divide by 60 if you want the result in minutes ;)

Answer (score 3):

Given this test table

```
create table a(a varchar(20));
insert into a values ('1 h 15 min'), ('1 h'), ('15 min');
```

this query

```
select
time_to_sec(str_to_date(a, '%l h %i min')) / 60 b
from a
having b is not null 
union all 
select
time_to_sec(str_to_date(a, '%i min')) / 60 b
from a
having b is not null
```

returns

```
b
75
60
15
```

Answer (score 2):

SQLFiddle appears to be down at the moment and I don't have a MySQL instance to hand so I've written this in SQL Server however it should translate with little issue

```
DECLARE @t table (
   horribly_formatted_time varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO @t (horribly_formatted_time)
  VALUES ('1 h 15 min')
       , ('15 h 59 min')
       , ('25 h 1 min')
       , ('1 h')
       , ('15 min')



SELECT horribly_formatted_time
     , hours
     , minutes
     , (Cast(hours As int) * 60) + Cast(minutes As int) As total_minutes
FROM   (
        SELECT horribly_formatted_time
             , SubString(remove_the_min, 0, separator) As hours
             , SubString(remove_the_min, separator + 3, 20) As minutes
        FROM   (
                SELECT horribly_formatted_time
                     , remove_the_min
                     , CharIndex(' h ', remove_the_min) As separator
                FROM   (
                        SELECT horribly_formatted_time
                             , Replace(consistant_format, ' min', '') As remove_the_min
                        FROM   (
                                  SELECT horribly_formatted_time
                                       , CASE
                                           WHEN horribly_formatted_time NOT LIKE '% min' THEN horribly_formatted_time + ' 0 min'
                                           WHEN horribly_formatted_time NOT LIKE '% h %' THEN '0 h ' + horribly_formatted_time
                                           ELSE horribly_formatted_time
                                         END As consistant_format
                                  FROM   @t
                                 ) As w
                       ) As x
               ) As y
       ) As z
```

Comment: This is obviously more verbose than necessary however it shows you each logical step in to achieving the desired result.

Comment: Thanks, @RandomeSeed answer was just _slightly_ sexier;)